# Linux SystemD Services - Simple vs Forked - Downsides?

Tags: linux, centos7, systemd, rhel7

A lot of programs you download can be run in a blocking manner or in the background (usually by start/stop/etc commands).  Some good examples are HA Proxy and Spring Boot apps built to be Linux services... both can be run in either manner.

In system-d unit files you can use "forked" type to allow you to map to start/stop/etc commands for managing a program that runs in the background/as a daemon.  Alternatively, you can just use the "simple" type and call the app itself in a blocking manner.

Is there any particular reason to prefer "forked" where it is an option?  Having done both options on numerous things, it seems "simple" is lighter on config and more obvious in terms of usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered in  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/daemon.html section "sysv daemons"  there are mostly only downsides of choosing the "forking" method, because most software out there, DO NOT perform the "15 steps" either correctly or at all, in particular, steps 12 and 14 are seldom correctly implemented.